# Programmatically adding a service call to SharePoint Call Center application

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am working with sharepoint and I am trying to add a service call to microsoft's call center application template. I can add one with just a name with the following code:

```
SPSite allSites = new SPSite(siteURL);
SPWeb site = allSites.AllWebs[siteName];
SPListItemCollection requestsList = site.Lists[serviceRequests].Items;
SPListItemCollection customerList = site.Lists[customers].Items;

SPListItem item = requestsList.Add();
item["Service Request"] = "Program Test";
//item["Customer"] = "Donald Duck";
item["Customer"] = customerList[0];
item.Update();
```

First I tried just using the customer name, which did not work. I then got the customer list and tried to use the customer list item instead, but I still get the same error:

> `"Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only."`

Does anyone have experience with adding information to sharepoint from code similar to this?  Is there someway I can determine which fields are read-only, if any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sometime happens when you have a Lookup Field and you don't specify the value for it. For Example when you have a List with the Following item

1. Customer : Text
2. Department : Lookup of Department List and Required.

   ```
   SPListItem item = requestsList.Add();        
   item["Customer"] = "as";
   item.Update();
   ```

Now you will get this error.Because you didnt specify the value for the Department field